# Match all words expect non duplicates

Tags: pcre

```
Hello Foo Bar World Foo World Bar Test Foo
foo bar
```

I want my regex to match everything but non duplicate words:

It should match all the following words in the test string: `Foo Bar World`
It shouldn't match: `Hello Test` because those are not duplicate.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is not a good task for regex. You may have [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You will get better answers if you explain what you want to do *and what you have tried* without focusing on regex.

Comment: You can write "a theorical pattern" to find these words, but the problem is that the complexity of the algorithm used with this kind of patterns will grow exponentially with the text size (the number of words to be exact). Thus you can't solve this kind of problem with these patterns. A more simple way is to split your text into separated words (or to match each word) and to count the number of occurrences in a second time (the best way if possible is to use an iterator and to increment a hash with the word as key).

Comment: I see, I was just curious whether this could be solved with regex or not. I already have other ways to solve it thanks :D

Comment: You can write something like this: https://regex101.com/r/kC8mC8/1 *(take a look at the number of steps needed, and copy the subject line several times to see what happens)*.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Holy **** the steps increase drastically.

Answer (score 0):

With positive look-ahead assertions you can. It's not especially efficient and I wouldn't use regex for the task.

```
/(\b\w++\b)(?=(?>.*?\1(?:.(?!\1))*)$)/gs
```

**Edit:** Missed [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte)'s comment answer, which is faster but less compatible.